# Is writing controller code in a view class not very MVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller

I have a `UITableViewController` and custom `UITableViewCell`, when I tap some button on the cell, controller should push to another controller and present another view.

I can think of two solutions for the code architect for this.

1. First one is that I create a protocol method to react to the tapping event in my cell and set controller as delegate, so once there is tapping on my cell, controller would react to push to another view.
2. But I could also do something in my cell class like this, instead of creating delegate, I keep asking the nextResponder if it's the right controller with `for` loop and once I get it I use it to push to the next one:

   ```
   @implementation MyCustomTableViewCell
   //...
   //...
   //...
   -(void)tappedOnSomeView
   {
       id obj = nil;
       for (obj = self; obj; obj = [obj nextResponder]) {
       if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyTableViewController class]])
       {
           UIViewController *uiVC = (UIViewController *)obj;
           MyNextViewController *nextVC = [[MyNextViewController alloc] init];
           [uiVC.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
                return;
           }
       }
   }
   //...
   //...
   //...
   @end
   ```

So is this not very MVC? Or is it ugly code? Should I just create delegate to handle all the gesture events on my cell in its tableview controller? Or is there another better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: option 1 is the better  approach

Comment: ALWAYS!!! ALWAYS! use the 1st approach you have mentioned!

Comment: Just so as to provide you another option, you could do something like this

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, add target to the view to handle the tap event... This way you can directly catch the response for the tap inside the view controller

Comment: Option 2 is bad, fragile, and tough to reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with the first approach. The benefit of this is that you can also pass back some data from the cell back to the view controller.

The other option is you could do something like this

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, add target to the view to handle the tap event.
This way you can directly catch the response for the tap inside the view controller. However I would emphasise on the 1st approach of delegate.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have many other different viewcontrollers that would use the same custom cell, then I would need to implement all the delegate methods of the cell in each viewcontroller, right? Would that be causing more duplicate code?

Comment: Yes. You will surely have to write the use delegate method in other view controllers, but I guess we all face this issue where we have to write some part of code redundantly as the architecture calls for it

Comment: Thanks, I will re-write my code then. Before I thought I need to not "repeat my self", but I think in this case it is what we have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Having user actions on custom table view cells is a common practice and per MVC, "view" should not take decisions like what to show, how to show, when to show. View should only know what things it needs to draw on what conditions. In your case, per MVC, first approach makes sense. Add your ViewController as delegate to cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and handle the pushing of new view controller in your controller!

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have many other different viewcontrollers that would use the same custom cell, then I would need to implement all the delegate methods of the cell in each viewcontroller, right? Would that be causing more duplicate code?

Comment: Yes, which to me is fine. This design makes code scalable and less prone to regression bugs. Code readability is at stake when your view start taking decisions...

Comment: Thanks, I will re-write my code then. Before I thought I need to not "repeat my self", but I think in this case it is what we have to do.